# Find available disk space for a network location using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Within a Rails App I am reading files on a network location using the following:

```
Dir.chdir('\\server\share')
Dir.glob('**/*.txt').each do |f|
    ....
end
```

I would like to find the available disk space at this directory (a Windows PC) using Ruby.

To find available bytes on a local disk I have previously used the [sys-filesystem](https://github.com/djberg96/sys-filesystem) gem:

```
require 'sys/filesystem'

stat = Sys::Filesystem.stat("C:\\")
bytes = stat.block_size * stat.blocks_available
```

I can only get sys-filesystem to return information for local disks or mounted network paths. The format of the network location is `\\server\share`.

Can anyone suggest an alternative?

Comment: You can use the Windows API,[ GetDiskFreeSpaceEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and [call it from Ruby](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/95347). The GetDiskFreeSpaceEx accepts UNC paths. You can also check if the gem you are using supports this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by lurker, the Windows API can return the free disk space:

```
require "Win32API"  

GetDiskFreeSpaceEx = Win32API.new("kernel32", "GetDiskFreeSpaceEx",
['p','p','p','p'], 'i')

def get_disk_free_space(path)
    free_caller = " " * 8
    total = " " * 8
    free = " " * 8
    GetDiskFreeSpaceEx.call(path, free_caller, total, free)
    l,h = free_caller.unpack("II")
    l + (h << 32)
end

path = "\\\\server\\share\\"
puts "#{get_disk_free_space(path)} bytes"
puts "#{(get_disk_free_space(path)/1073741824.0).round(2)} GB"
```

Ensuring that the path has a trailing backslash.